# IFERROR not returning an array and thus breaking the SUMPRODUCT result

Tags: excel-formula

- I have a column in a spreadsheet in which numbers are sometimes
  stored in text format or are mixed with text values.
- For converting them to numbers I would
  normally use VALUE. And because of the other text values in the same column I would additionally wrap it
  with IFERROR, defaulting the result to 0 to prevent any issues with the
  conversion.
- All this I wanted to use in SUMPRODUCT and I am reluctant to add any new intermediate columns to the sheet.

I face an issue with IFERROR returning a single value (or even a #VALUE! error) when it is used in SUMPRODUCT as one of the arrays. What's even worse, the sum is correctly assessed in the Function Arguments window.

I created an isolated case, that you can see here [SUMPRODUCT using IFERROR problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aupyt.png). One of the numbers in column C is preceded with with single quotation "**'**" and the C column holds both text and number values.

A long version of the SUMPRODUCT formula 
`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VALUE($C1:$C4),0),--($D1:$D4="yes"),--NOT(ISERROR($C$1:$C$4+1-1)),--(($C1:$C4)<>""))` and the simplified one `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VALUE(C19:C21),0))`. It returns a correct number in the Function Arguments window when in the spreadsheet it shows #VALUE! error or respectively an incorrect sum.

I wonder if I am using the aforementioned functions wrong (can't IFERROR be used as an array here?), or is this some sort of an Excel bug (why the assessed value is different from the result in the spreadsheet?).

Thanks in advance for your comments and suggesting a solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)". A link to an image isn't a substitute for a small example of the spreadsheet that demonstrates the problem. We can't copy and paste the spreadsheet into our own to test, we have to re-enter everything and hope we get it right.

Comment: With IFERROR the formula will need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: @BigBen It was a typo in the question"s text, but not in Excel. But thanks for noting. I've corrected it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Many thanks for your suggestion. I would swear I have checked it before, but I tried again and now it worked. Great!

Comment: @ScottCraner so in the Excel insiders version CSE is no longer needed, right?

Comment: @BigBen yup, no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VALUE($C1:$C4),0),--($D1:$D4="yes"),--NOT(ISERROR($C$1:$C$4+1-1)),--(($C1:$C4)<>""))
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VALUE(C19:C21),0))
```

all need to be confirmed with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Another option,

Change your formula into :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(+$C1:$C4),--($D1:$D4="yes"),--NOT(ISERROR($C$1:$C$4+1-1)),--(($C1:$C4)<>""))
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(+C19:C21))
```

the change using N(+.... instead of IFERROR(VALUE(....

also, the above 2 formulas need not array entry

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Enter works for me as suggested by @ScottCraner before. And as described in the original question, please note that one of the numbers in column C is preceded with with single quotation. It is "**'25**". For me the N function doesn't convert this value to the correct number, but to 0.